# Why would the reflection of a lamp by a bowl look like a heart?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, geometric-optics

I have this bowl roughly the shape of a circular truncated cone, and the lamp shines on the bowl at an angle. The reflected lamp light hit the bottom of the bowl and created a light ring that looks just like a cardioid. Could someone help me, or give me a hint on how to really solve the equation for the light ring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct. If the angle at which the lamp shines is just right, the **catacaustic** (the envelope of rays reflected from a point) is a cardioid, as for example in this picture:

[image]

In particular, if the light reflects inside the bowl (which from above looks circular) from a point on the inner edge, you have the situation in the bottom left figure:

[image]

The general formula for a catacaustic generated by a source point and a reflecting curve is given on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28mathematics%29). For a circle, the curve can be parametrized as $(\cos t, \sin t)$, and given a source point on the circle (e.g. $(1,0)$), the resulting catacaustic should be a cardioid (see equations (5) and (6) on this [Wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleCatacaustic.html)).

Comment: Pretty pictures!

Comment: Technically the curve is actually a nephroid rather than a cardiod.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are seeing is a [cardioid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid), which is the [caustic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28mathematics%29) formed by light reflecting off of a cylinder.